# react-router 1.0 Error: Uncaught TypeError: getCurrentLocation is not a function | createHistory.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Getting Uncaught TypeError: getCurrentLocation is not a function in createHistory.js while implementing react-router. What is wrong in my code?

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;
var history = require('history');
var createHistory = require('history/lib/createHistory');
var useBasename = require('history/lib/useBasename');


var Login = require('./components/login');
var App = require('./components/App');


var appHistory  = useBasename(createHistory)({
  basename: '/test'
})

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={appHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="login" component={Login}/>      
      <IndexRoute component={Login}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('content'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to use `createHistory` directly from the `history` package. Instead use one of the actual history factories like `createBrowserHistory` or `createHashHistory`.